# How to intercept execution in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssms, vsix

I'm trying to find any guideline how to intercept query execution in SQL Server Management Studio.

For example: I want to check query for `WHERE` clause after "Execute" button click.
I already created add on in VS19 with VSIX project.
I want to stop the query if it have `WHERE` clause in it , only for my own login and only from  SQL Server Management Studio.
Should I catch button click, or can it be done by interception of inner SSMS commands?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to stop the query or you can analyse it after the execution? Do you want to intercept all queries from all logins or just your own? Do you want to intercept only queries from SSMS or any other source too? The amount of queries might be huge if you want to see everything.

Comment: I want to stop the query if it have Where clause in it , only for my own login and only from SSMS. 
As I understand I probably need to subscribe to execute event , but I don't know how to catch it and what fires it.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture SQL trace data and executed SQL statements using the SQL Server Profiler - in SSMS, go to Tools -> SQL Server Profiler.

There are many videos and tutorials on the web on what to capture, but generally speaking, if you are using the Standard template, you should be able to do the following.

- Prep your development environment and get up to the point where you're about to click the button.
- Start the Profiler trace. Tip: you should "Enable trace stop time" in case an app or something locks up your UI.
- Click the button that executes the SQL.
- Stop the trace.

The SQL that you are looking to find should be listed in the trace.

Things to note:

- Profile tracing affects SQL performance - limit the trace time especially if it will affect others
- If you are running this against a SQL server not on your local machine, you may not be able to run the trace (due to security settings)
- The Standard template captures ALOT of events. Be prepared to search
- Once you get the hang of it, you can uncheck unwanted trace data and filter for specific information

Comment: So if I catch event that I want, my next step will be somehow subscribe to this event, read the environment variables and change it. Do you know ,can I make it in my VSIX project in witch I added toolbar to SSMS ?

Comment: I re-read your question several times and think I misunderstood it. Now I think that you're trying to create an SSMS extension that looks at the query you're trying to run to see if it has a WHERE clause in it. If so, you want to do other work on the SQL statement prior to executing it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Can you describe what do you plan to do, after you have intercepted the execution?
I deveop SSMSBoost add-in, we intercept executions without WHERE or "TRUNCATES". Maybe we can add functionality that you want, if it is useful for other users.

Comment: If my UPDATE query doesn't have WHERE clause it should give an message with something like "Do you want to proceed this without WHERE ?" . And it will not execute before user will click yes or not .
I don't know if you could but it will be awesome if you can share some code examples how do you intercept EXECUTE button click , or just share general idea and libraries/tools/vsix methods which you use to do it ?

Comment: This feature is already present in SSMSBoost for SQL Server Management Studio. (Fatal Actions Guard)
We do not have currently separate version for Visual Studio, but we plan to create it. However, most probably, about 60% of hooks and features must be re-implemented.